# mongo count(*) with php but without sending all result array

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, count

I am writing my scripts in PHP and I try to convert SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rank  
FROM user    
WHERE  user.lvl > $user_level
```

query to Mongo.

I found only one decision:

```
$nosql = array(
     'lvl' => array('$gt' => $user_level)
);    
$result = $collection->find($nosql);
$length = count(iterator_to_array($result));
```

1. get all objects which satisfy the condition
2. And count them in PHP

It is possible to get count of needed objects without sending all array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongodb can `count` result like this  you didn't need to use `count(iterator_to_array($result));`

```
$nosql = array(
 'lvl' => array('$gt' => $user_level)
);    
$result = $collection->find($nosql);
$length = $result->count();
```

Comment: It is the same what i write in "Topic Post": We send query to MongoDB, it returns a looooong Array with objects and then we count this array of elements in PHP.
Can we get only count number from Mongo? Without objects themselves. P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: `$result->count();` is not semilar  `count(iterator_to_array($result));` this only return count number . with `print_r($result);` you can see count  number

Answer (score 1):

The new driver does not implement  `$cursor->count()` use `$collection->count()` instead

```
$collection->count($filter)
```